# Alter a path alias depending on a node property

Tags: uri

I use the Pathauto module and I'm trying to get, for the same content type, two different path aliases depending on a Boolean field that content type has.

I would like to have a path alias like mysite/node_name if the Boolean field value is false and  mysite/[a generic term]/node_name if its value is true.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Create a custom node token which outputs a blank string if the node field value is false, and the generic string if it's true. Then use that token as the 2nd URL part, and pathauto will take care of removing the extra slash if the token value is empty

Answer (score 1):

if you don't won’t to create a new token as @Clive mentioned in comment, you can use `hook_pathauto_alias_alter` in your custom module like the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  if ($context['module'] === 'node' && $context['bundle'] === 'MY_BUNDLE') {
    // Get the node.
    $node = $context['data']['node'];

    // Clean string service.
    $clean_string_service = \Drupal::service('pathauto.alias_cleaner');

    $is_checked = $node->field_SOME_NAME->value;
    //   If your field is checked.
    if ($is_checked === 1) {
      $alias = '/mysite/term/' . $clean_string_service->cleanString($node->label());
    }
    else {
      $alias = '/mysite/' . $clean_string_service->cleanString($node->label());
    }
  }
}
```